# NAudio and DirectX 12

Tags: c#, directx-11, naudio, directx-12

I'm getting a DirectX sourced error when using NAudio.  I'm not that knowledgeable when it comes to DirectX so would appreciate some pointers.

There error I am receiving when getting NAudio initialized on a windows 10 PC with DirectX 12 install is this:

> NAudio.Dmo.DmoResampler..ctor
>      System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Retrieving the COM class factory   for component with CLSID {F447B69E-1884-4A7E-8055-346F74D6EDB3} failed due to the  following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from >HRESULT:  0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).
>
> NAudio.Dmo.DmoResampler..ctor
>
> NAudio.Wave.ResamplerDmoStream..ctor   IWaveProvider inputProvider,     WaveFormat outputFormat
>
> NAudio.Wave.WasapiOut.Init IWaveProvider waveProvider
>
> Sound.Support.AudioPlaybackEngine..ctor    MMDevice device, Int32 sampleRate, Int32 channelCount
>
> Sound.Manager.PerformInitialization
>
> Analyze.ViewModels.ApplicationViewModel.InitSoundManager

Okay, it's pretty obvious some COM object isn't registered, so what to do?

Here's the code invoking  NAudio:

```
    public AudioPlaybackEngine(MMDevice device, int sampleRate = 44100, int channelCount = 2)
    {
        Device = device;

        mOutputDevice = new WasapiOut(device,
                                      AudioClientShareMode.Shared,
                                      true,
                                      200);

        mMixer = new MixingSampleProvider(WaveFormat.CreateIeeeFloatWaveFormat(sampleRate, channelCount))
                {
                    ReadFully = true
                };

        mMixer.MixerInputEnded += OnMixerInputEnded;

        mOutputDevice.Init(mMixer);
        mOutputDevice.Play();
    }
```

The fault occurs on the first call.

This works just fine on DirectX 11, on any platform

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows 10 has DirectX 9.0c through DirectX 12 all side-by-side. This is probably better considered a Media Foundation question.

That GUID (`{F447B69E-1884-4A7E-8055-346F74D6EDB3}`) appears to be the Resampler DMO (DirectX Media Objects). [DMOs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375474.aspx) were part of the legacy DirectShow technologies which are primarily used today by the Media Foundation APIs--I won't get into the tortured history of how "DirectShow" originally called "ActiveMovie" ended up being branded DirectX, but needless to say the technology was [removed](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2012/08/21/directx-sdks-of-a-certain-age/) from the DirectX SDK back in 2005.

Therefore, my question would be: **are you using a N or KN edition of Windows 10?** If so, then it does not contain Media Foundation by default. You have to install it via a [Restore Pack](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3145500). See [Who moved my Windows Media Cheese?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2010/08/13/who-moved-my-windows-media-cheese/).

> You can try using [this sample program](https://github.com/mvaneerde/blog/tree/master/dmoenum) to ensure the GUID is present on your machine.

If you are developing a Universal Windows Platform (UWP) app rather than classic Win32 desktop app, there might also be some restrictions on available transforms that could be impacting you.

Comment: It's odd as the customer experiencing the problem is in the US and is seeing it on two different machines.  At least this gives me a road to head down to start finding the problem. (It is a plain old WPF app if there is such a thing).  Thanks for the pointers.